# Which Red Hat Enterprise Linux packages for CentOS?

Tags: centos, rhel, rpm

I want to use a Red Hat Enterprise Linux RPM software package on CentOS 5.6, but I don't know which version of RHEL works with CentOS 5.6.

RHEL 4 = CentOS 4?

RHEL 5 = CentOS 5?

...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version numbers correlate between RHEL and CentOS (as Ben Preston already answered). Moreover, due to RHEL philosophy, the ABI should stay the same across all minor number ( .x) versions, so the package compiled for 5.4 should most likely work for 5.5 and 5.6 as well.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to install RHEL packages on CentOS, just install native ones. Unless you are talking of third-party packages.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the version numbers correlate between RHEL and CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS uses the source packages of RHEL to create the CentOS OS. So OS versions are the same in both the cases. 
CentOS is the carbon copy version of RHEL with better support for drivers and packages which RHEL cannot support due to its policies. You get a lot of packages from [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) for CentOS.

You can use a rpm package for CentOS, keep in mind your architecture and your version.

Comment: CentOS ships the same stuff as RHEL. There are extraofficial repositorios with stuff that RHEL doesn't ship, mostly for stability/reduncancy reasons (EPEL) and probably others that carry stuff Red Hat can't ship legally (or just don't want to run the risk for little gain) due to licensing concerns (in USA, mostly).